# Possibility to login without password

Tags: plugins, login, wp-login-form, authentication

I'm creating a webapplication for users that are racing in a rally.

I have the following data from the different racers:

- Username
- Password
- Mobile phone
- Email

The problem is they never know their password. Is it possible for them to login without password? Maybe with a code on their mobile phone or .. ? (they will always login with mobile phone)

Comment: Nonsense! Password is _authentication_, which together with _identification_ are parts of the login process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you can easily just ask for a user name and/or email or text/email them their OTP(one time password).

This is becoming more popular on mobile apps that ask for just a phone number and text a code to enter for authentication.

Examples
https://auth0.com/blog/how-passwordless-authentication-works/
https://www.okta.com/security-blog/2018/04/is-passwordless-authentication-actually-secure/

For wordpress auth there are plugins already.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/passwordless-login/